# Something wrong with edittext in the same LinearLayout and focusing

Tags: android, focus, android-linearlayout

I'm wondering something...
I'm don't know why the focus don't work between the 2 edittext when i'm using this :

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:hint="@string/etEmail_init"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" 
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:contentDescription="@string/textInvalide"
    android:src="@drawable/cancel" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etEmail3"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:hint="@string/etEmail_init"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" 
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The one solution i've found is to put each edit text in 2 LinearLayout...
But what i want to do is to have these edittext on the same "line"...

Anyone have an idea ?
Thx in advance !
Sebastien

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<EditText android:id="@+id/et1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" />
<EditText android:id="@+id/et2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1.0" android:background="#ffffff"  android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="1px">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"  android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/date" android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"  android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <ImageView
android:id="@+id/ivEmail"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:contentDescription="@string/textInvalide"
android:src="@drawable/anyimage" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="0.5" >

        <EditText android:id="@+id/time" android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:paddingLeft="5px" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Ckeck this out this gonna definitely help u sebestian :)
welcome